# Forward pointer to value, not value itself

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to have array of poiners to array of chars... (weird, I know, but I can't use STL lib)
So I've declared it as : `const char *** DbRecord;  DbRecord = new const char**[1000];`

And then I've got this function:

```
 bool AddToArray(const char* value,
        const char *** database);
```

how to store pointer to that `const char * value` to my DbRecord on position `[0]` ? And how to access it then to be able to read the value, which is actually saved there and not the pointer? I'm really confused about about pointers in C++ :-/ Thanks for the explanation...

Comment: Frankly, you lost me with the third `*`.

Comment: Congratulations. You are now a three-star programmer. (Seriously, either use the standard library or stop programming in C++ immediately.)

Comment: What. The. Holy. F*ck. Are. Those. Three. Asterisks. Doing. There?

Comment: No, I think he's three-star confused.  There's nothing wrong with triple indirection, actually.  But not recommended for someone who is "confused about pointers in C++".

Comment: Why did you tag as C? `bool` is not a valid C type. Why can you not use the standard library?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What about `stdbool.h`?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel still, he's using `new`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: `_Bool`.

Comment: @BenVoigt `_Bool` is built-in, `<stdbool.h>` defines `bool` as a typedef.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas sry... Wrong tag...my bad :]

Comment: use typedefs for your intermediate types to help you out figuring which is which.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know...I sucessfuly wrote it with `string **`, but as I've said - I can't use `STL`, thus I can't use `string`. That's why I'm using `char *`

Comment: @Dworza `std::string` isn't part of the STL. It's part of the _C++ Standard Library_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to store pointer to that const char * value to my DbRecord on position [0] ?

You can't, because `value` will go out of scope once the function ends.

Do you really need three  stars? It seems to me two should be sufficient:

```
const char** DbRecord;
DbRecord = new const char*[1000];

void AddToArray(const char* value, const char** database)
{
    database[0] = value;
}
```

Comment: I must use `***` because it's homework for practicing algorithmization and I'll have to sort and search the array frequently, so array of pouinters would be much faster then array of values.

Comment: Are you implying that a `const char**` is faster than a `const char*`? Because it most certainly isn't. All object pointers are of the same size.

Comment: @Dworza You definitely need to [get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Nope.. I will have records like : id, name, adress, city ...Nevertheless for example city will have only a few unique records so it would be good to make only pointers to those values... So I need `char*` to store the actual value beacuse I can't use `string`, then another `*` to create array of those chars and the third one `*` to have pointers to those array indexes? Am I right?

Comment: If you have one C string "London", then you can have as many `char*`s to it as you want. You only pay one machine word for each. If you insist on storing `char**`s instead, you also pay one machine word for each `char**`, but you also have to pay one additional machine word for that single shared `char*`. So with `char**` you end up with more memory and more dereferencing.

Comment: Note that for `string`s, assignment means copying of the underlying char array, whereas for `char*`s, assignment means sharing of the char array. When you go from `string` to `char*` and you want sharing, you don't need that extra `*`, because `char*` already has the desired "sharing semantics". Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

DbRecord is an array of pointers that points to `const char **`, so when you say `DbRecord[0]` it really means the first row of a 3D char array, which elements are of `const char**` type. So `DbRecord[0][0] = value` will store the variable `value` at `index row [0][0]` if this is what you want.

When you allocate memory for DbRecord, only doing

```
DbRecord = new const char**[1000];
```

is not enough, you have to set size of the other two dimensions.

You can try to use `std::string` to replace `const char *` and `vector<vector<string>>`  to replace
`const char ***` in C++, in which case, you don't need to worry about those pointers anymore.

Comment: as I've said - I am very limited on imports... I can't use `string` and `vector` as well... that's why I want to create that awful structure `char ***`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You asked your question simple enough. :)

> I want to have array of poiners to array of chars...

You're on the right track. At the very least that is `char *[]`. However, as we all know, that can easily be translated to `char **`. Of course, to have a pointer to the storage, you need to add the third star. You're correct so far in your question.

> how to store pointer to that const char * value to my DbRecord on position [0]

Well there are two ways to do it. The correct answer to the question *the way you asked it* is to **dereference** the pointer. For example:

```
bool AddToArray(const char* value,
    const char *** database)
{
    bool success = false;
    ((*database)[0]) = value;
    if ( (*database)[0] == value ) success == true;
    return success;
}
```

Technically, accessing a pointer as an array will also dereference it as an index. So the `[0]` there will dereference the pointer straight. Depending on how you lay out your allocations and memory, you could also do it like this:

```
...
(*(database[0])) = value;
...
```

Note the subtle difference there. Where the first example treated it as a *pointer to an array of pointers* (or a pointer to an array of arrays, depending on how you think of it), this second example treats it as an *array of pointers to an array* (or an array of pointers to pointers).

Learning to master multiple levels of pointers is one of the best things you can do as a C developer but it's generally a frowned-upon practice in C++.

Hope this helps.

Edit: `char *[]` not `char [][]`

Comment: There is no such thing as `char [][]` in either C or C++.

Comment: That's funny, it compiles just fine in g++ with -pedantic

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://ideone.com/FCkLdX): `error: declaration of ‘a’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first`

Comment: @inetknght: Even if it did, that would be irrelevant, as there's a fine chance that it's just an extension.

Comment: Technically I'm wrong in that it's a double array so incorrect for the answer; I'll edit that for correction. But it's valid construct. http://pastebin.com/FNkhPa7d

I'm sure you can see where I was wrong.